# Regression testing for Flutter app using Dart?

Tags: flutter, mobile, automation

Is it possible somehow to test a mobile flutter app using something like Appium+WDIO+Appium Flutter Driver but Dart instead ?
I mean that it is important to make it as separated repository and not to rely on the code, just to the build.

For example I'd like to have something like a repository which will contain application itself, configs for devices  and tests. Tests get access to the application and I just automate some functionality using Keys or smth else.

I'm new to flutter and don't know a lot about it, but would like to. Currently I have some problems with using Appium Flutter Driver and that's the main reason why I'm asking this maybe "stupid" question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an integration testing tool for Flutter in which you write tests in Dart, you're probably looking for [Patrol](https://patrol.leancode.co).

You can learn more about it in the docs from the link above or the Fluttercon talk given by their team (which also covers how appium-flutter-driver doesn't work fully as we'd like):

[image]

Comment: I second that - though I may not be objective since I wrote most of Patrol :) Anyway, I hope Patrol will help you write good test your app. If you have any problems, please create an Issue or a Discussion on our GitHub: https://github.com/leancodepl/patrol – we're doing our best to support the community.

Comment: Thanks a lot, maybe that's what I am exactly looking for <3